# Create user in Firebase from authenticated user

Tags: flutter, dart

I have set up an Auth class to handle all sign in methods that store the authenticated user.

Pass my authenticated user to Provider on landing page to decided page flow if authenticated.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final auth = Provider.of<AuthBase>(context);
//get provider instace
return StreamBuilder<User>(
    stream: auth.onAuthStateChanged,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
        User user = snapshot.data;
        if (user == null) {
          return SignInScreen();
        } else //add this user to proivders
          return Provider<RegisteredUser>(
              builder: (context) => FireStoreDatabase( uid: user.uid),
              child: HomeScreen());
      } else {
        return Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          ),
        );
      }
    });
}
```

If the user is Authenticated, return to HomeScreen.

I have another provider for registered users. From here, I take the Auth user and pass it to the provider to check if an Authenticated user exists in Firebase doc.

If not, Authenticated user pushed to Register page and pop details then information set in Firebase database and value passed to new variable >user

```
abstract class RegisteredUser {
  Future<void> creatUserInFirestore(context, uid);
}
class FireStoreDatabase implements RegisteredUser {
  FireStoreDatabase({this.uid}) : assert(uid != null);
  final String uid;
  Future<void> creatUserInFirestore(context, uid) async {
    User user = uid;
    DocumentSnapshot doc = await usersRef.document(user.uid).get();
    if (!doc.exists) {
      final username = await Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => CreateAccount(),
        ),
      );
      usersRef.document(user.uid).setData({
        "id": user.uid,
        "username": username,
        "photoUrl": user.photoUrl,
        "email": user.email,
        "displayName": user.displayName,
        "bio": "",
        "timestamp": timestamp,
        "travelMethod": "",
        "website": "",
      });
      doc = await usersRef.document(user.uid).get();
    }
    user = User.fromDocument(doc);
    print(user.displayName);
    print("This is the uid: $uid");
  }
}
```

Cannot get to work. Console prints do not show any record.

Please advise me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
final username = await Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => CreateAccount(),
        ),
      );`
```

I guess `username` is void and keep in mind you are also awaiting for the return.

> Returns a [Future] that completes to the `result` value passed to
>   [pop] when the pushed route is popped off the navigator.

Also do not pass a context to a service class only so you can navigate. Implementations for the auth/user api should be in the auth/user api class.

> Gather together the things that change for the same reasons. Separate
>   those things that change for different reasons.

I'm following this great architecture which I highly recommend:
https://www.filledstacks.com/post/flutter-provider-v3-architecture/

For your routing context problem:
https://www.filledstacks.com/post/navigate-without-build-context-in-flutter-using-a-navigation-service/